# MS SQL login periodically doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, profiler

- **Instance info:** Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
- **Location:** AWS

A Java app on another AWS server logs into the SQL instance using a local SQL account, and 95% of the time, the login connects, and everything is fine. The other 5% I get following error:

> "Login failed for user 'Blah.' Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'Blah_Database.' [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]"

I know the 2 IP's that the login request is coming from and the connection string names the database which is present. The permissions are set correctly.
I've captured the event running a Profiler Trace looking for Event Class "Audit Failed Login." But, This doesn't give me any more info than the SQL error log.

Any other event classes I can add to the profiler to gather more info?

I've verified the the database Auto-Close feature is off. I've also increased the remote login timeout to 30.

Comment: Thanks John, I know the IP that the login is coming (there are two actually) and they specify a database in the connection string. My problem is that the database is there and it works 95% of the time.

Comment: Is there a load balancer that 95% of the time point to a DB that exist and sometimes, 5% of the time to a DB that was maybe deleted but the IP address is still in the load balancer informations? Just guessing.

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll check on that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps AWS has some stuff similar to Azure Serverles' functionality? I.e., it takes a while to spin up the database. I would increase the connection timeout drastically as a first test and then take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

@Alonzo, once it happened to me that we upgraded a software through a `setup.exe` file.

The installation was fine but because there was a load balancer involved the upgrade actually took place only on 4 databases out of 5.
In the end 80% of our transactions were successful and 20% were failing for no reason.

**It took us some time to understand that we had to manually apply that upgrade also on the 5th database.**

So check if you find yourself in this scenario.